# What environment variables I need to set / configure in Eclipse (for Selenium WebDriver)? What if I don't set / configure them?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have read posts online that if one wish to work with Eclipse / Selenium WebDriver, he need to install Java first, then set / configure JAVA_HOME, then download Maven and set MAVEN_HOME environment variable, then update PATH variables, etc BEFORE ONE START WORKING with Eclipse / Selenium WebDriver.

Would appreciate your answers on following:

1) What if I don't set / create ANY of the above said environment variables and start working in Eclipse?

2) I tried to run some of automate tests (already created before) in Eclipse / Selenium WebDriver. When I ran them in Debug Mode, I was frequently getting "Source not found" error which I tried to fix but still getting it (Please check screenshots of those errors).

Am I getting "Source not found" error because [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zb5Hp.png)above said environment variables are not yet set?
[image]

3) I know I can to set environment variables (on Windows 10) by right-clicking on "This PC" > More > Properties > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables > and created those I need BUT I don't have admin rights on my system - in the meanwhile, is there any other way to set these environment variables (e.g., using Command Prompt or any other way)?

4) I spent hours on fixing "Source not found" error, downloaded multiple versions of Eclipse but still not able to get rid of it. Any best way to fix this error?

5) Also I don't find CLASSPATH under "System variables". Should I be concerned?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvcoF.png)
[image]

Comment: Not familiar with Eclipse, but I highly recommend you to use Intellij IDEA instead of Eclipse. Intellij is more powerful and user-friendly. Thus you can rapidly set the env variable there.

Comment: Will try Intellij as getting frequent "Source not found" is annoying in Eclipse. And now it failed to stop on the lines where I set breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set JAVA_HOME, that's not optional in your case. MAVEN_HOME is optional and have alternatives.

Comment: What alternatives we have for setting MAVEN_HOME ?